# Allow XCode installed from dmg file to be updated from app store

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, xcode, mac-app-store

I recently installed the XCode 6 GM seed from a dmg file downloaded from Apple's developer portal. Now that XCode 6.0.1 is available on the Mac App Store, I would like for it to show as an update in the app store application itself.

How can I update XCode (on any application available in the App Store for that matter) installed from a dmg from the App Store?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not appearing in your purchases list then try unhide it.
To unhide an item follow these steps:

```
1. Open the Mac App Store.
2. Choose Store > Sign In, then enter your Apple ID and password.
3. Choose Store > View My Account.
4. Click View Hidden Purchases from the Account Information page.
5. From the Hidden Purchases page, locate the app you want to unhide.
6. Click the Unhide button.
```

If it does not appear in the hidden purchases list then you'll have to uninstall your current version of Xcode and reinstall it from App Store.

Comment: I have XCode installed from an external source (i.e. the DMG). The new version just has 'Install' as an option on the App Store. If I click on that, it will install a new XCode alongside the existing one. Is there a way for it to be overwritten automatically?

Comment: The Xcode image you downloaded from the Apple Developer website would of had to been registered to your Apple ID so it may count as a purchase similar to if you register for a beta version of OS X Yosemite then it will appear in the Mac App Store as a purchase.